# Android Java SoundPool.setRate not working on Nexus S

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I'm trying to change dynamically the pitch of a sound from code using **SoundPool.setRate**
Everything works fine when i run the code from the Android Virtual Device, but when i test it on my Nexus S the pitch dosn't change.
Any suggesiton?

Comment: Any work around or solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug which is present in the soundPool class for 4.2 and above. I would recommend you try using the mediaPlayer instead if you are dealing with audio in android. Check out the link: http://gc.codehum.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58113